# Could Oracle RecycleBin get cleaned automatically

Tags: oracle

In an AWR report, I observed following queries getting execured.

```
delete from RecycleBin$ where bo=:1

delete from RecycleBin$ where purgeobj=:1
```

As per our DBA, those were executed from the application host. But we are sure that we do not execute from the application. Is there any chance that some query executed by application caused this?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it gets cleaned automatically.

When you drop a table called let's say `TABLE_1`, it is not deleted from the datafile. The `TABLE_1` object entry is removed, but a new entry for this table is created in `RECYCLEBIN$` in case you want to restore it.

As you create new objects and insert data in existing tables in the same tablespace, at some point the data blocks originally belonging to `TABLE_1` will be reused and overwritten. When that happens, `TABLE_1` can no longer be restored from the recycle bin and the database automatically removes the entry from `RECYCLEBIN$`.

Comment: Thank you very for the answer. But we don't drop tables in our application

Comment: If `delete from RecycleBin$ where bo=:1` is showing up in an AWR report, it's consuming a decent amount of CPU, which would only happen if someone or some job was issuing `PURGE RECYCLEBIN` against a lot of objects. I've positively verified that that exact SQL, with the mixed-case object reference `RecycleBin$` (unusual for internal Oracle code), happens during a purge, but I've never seen it show up in any other situation. Oracle may use something entirely different for overwrites, but even if it reused the same delete it would be so fast it wouldn't show up in AWR or anybody's radar.

Comment: @PaulW And I've positively verified before posting that `delete from RecycleBin$                     where bo=:1` is executed during the automatic removal from `Recyclebin$`, it took maybe 1 minute to test it.

Comment: Yes, I said it might reuse the same SQL, but did it show up in an AWR report? How many seconds did it clock?

Comment: @PaulW Of course I didn't check, but an artificial example could be constructed to make it show up in the AWR. It is executed not only by manually executing PURGE, but automatically as well - what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any chance that some query executed by application caused this?

Yes, if you run `PURGE RECYCLEBIN`.

Comment: From our application, we execute only general INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE queries on application tables

Comment: @Sajith, check for any scheduler jobs that have been set up under your application schema. Those queries are fired internally by Oracle when you do `PURGE RECYCLEBIN` or `PURGE USER_RECYCLEBIN`, which isn't something Oracle would do on it's own, so there must be some scheduled job somewhere doing it. Ask your DBA to look more carefully at it to find out what program and client host is executing it.